# Using Facebook Javascript SDK when embedding the social plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I'm using Facebook [Social Plugin (Like Box)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) on my website. I can see that Facebook Javascript SDK has been included on my page as well. Is this now available to me for use? Can I get the number of fans using this sdk for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to call your page ID:

```
FB.api('/' + pageId, function( r ) {
  var likes = r.likes
});
```

But, you must make sure FB sdk have been loaded before (if it's loaded asynchronously). So, make sure it's loaded by assigning a function to `fbAsyncInit`:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {};
```

This function will be called once the SDK is loaded.

Comment: This was a perfect answer. Thank you so much.